# Unable to return only time from datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some columns which has time in string format like '01:19:55' and so on. I want to convert this string into time format. For that, I am trying to use the code like below:

col_list2=['clm_rcvd_tm','gtwy_rcvd_tm']

pandas_df_1=df2.toPandas()

for x in col_list2:

```
pandas_df_1[x]=pd.to_datetime(pandas_df_1[x].replace(" ",""),format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

As an output, these clumns are returning decimal values. (Ex:0.26974537037037)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `01:19:55` is a valid and appropriate time format. What do you need? Explain. Also you can see [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) for a reference on datetime manipulation.

Comment: its data type is string, I want it to be time data type

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string in your pandas dataframe as you mentioned i.e;
**01:19:55** so that you can easily convert this by using python `datetime` module

For example;

```
import datetime
str = "01:19:55"
dt = datetime.strptime(str, '%H:%M:%S') # for 24 hour format
dt = datetime.strptime(str, '%I:%M:%S') # for 12 hour format
```

for references have a look
[Python Datetime formating](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime)

Comment: The above code is also returning date part along time (Ex :2021-10-18 06:28:26)